# Why does this code compile with g++ but not MSVC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14

I'm trying to compile some open-source code (https://github.com/BieremaBoyzProgramming/bbpPairings), which I can get to compile on linux using `g++` (v6.3.0), but which fails to compile in Visual Studio (VS Community 2019/16.1.5), with the somewhat obscure (to me, but my C++ is admittedly weak) error: "error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<'".

The offending code in the source is [here](https://github.com/BieremaBoyzProgramming/bbpPairings/blob/master/tournament/generator.cpp#L88), but a minimal example extracted from the code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

class Configuration {};

class MatchesConfiguration {
public:
    template <class RandomEngine>
    MatchesConfiguration(
        Configuration&&,
        RandomEngine&);
};

template <class RandomEngine>
MatchesConfiguration::MatchesConfiguration(
    Configuration&& configuration,
    RandomEngine& randomEngine) {}

template
MatchesConfiguration::MatchesConfiguration<std::minstd_rand>( // <--- SYNTAX ERROR HERE
    Configuration&&,
    std::minstd_rand&);

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
}
```

I've had a look at the [MSDN description of the error code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2143?view=vs-2019), but my grasp of C++ and templates is too tenuous to figure out what's going wrong. The project README says that C++14 is expected (with some optional C++17 stuff for FS stuff which shouldn't matter here I think), but as far as I can make out from the [feature compatibility chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019) all of C++14 should be supported by VS 2019.

Comment: I can't get it to compile [on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/732fa945a6f3c056), which uses g++ 8.2.0.

Comment: I'm not that experienced in the newer versions of MSVC++, but this smells like a compatibility setting within the application. I think, by default, g++ v6.3.0 is likely compiling expecting an older version of the C++ language. g++ 6.5 was released according to https://gcc.gnu.org/ in Oct of last year, so I would expect 6.3.0 was significantly earlier. It's possible you need to set compatibility in MSVC++ to conform to an older version of the language.

Comment: Just for giggles, what happens if you add a space between the `>` and the `(` on that offending line? Does that enable it to compile?

Comment: Fails to compile on all tested compilers live: https://godbolt.org/z/pznS19

Comment: Yeah, the small code fails to compile in general I think. I dumbly copy-pasted it into CS to check that it provoked the syntax error, but forgot to check it on g++. Just a sec and I'll fix the small code.

Comment: do you want this https://godbolt.org/z/hpj4dK?

Comment: @Jarod42 The template is on the function, not the type.

Comment: Is that lonely `template` thing allowed? Shouldn't it be `template<>`?

Comment: There. Minimal example work on g++ now, but still gets the same error in VS.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663166/c-constructor-template-specialization/38663378

Comment: You are not calling any of the template in your main function. I assume g++ ignores the templates since it is not used.

Comment: Similar/duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36166531/how-to-explicit-instantiate-template-constructor-in-c

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel No. `template<>` is for explicit specialization, however this code is doing explicit instantiation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you provide an [explicit instantiation definition](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit#2) of a [constructor](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor#1) (which does not really have a name according to the standard), you should do it by supplying the signature you'd like to instantiate, like so:

```
template
MatchesConfiguration::MatchesConfiguration(  // no <std::minstd_rand> here
    Configuration&&,
    std::minstd_rand&);
```

[[temp.arg.explicit#2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.explicit#2)]

> Template arguments shall not be specified when referring to a
>   specialization of a constructor template

---

Trivia from an old note (from 2006):
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#581

"*Can a templated constructor be explicitly instantiated or specialized?*"

> it is not possible to specify a constructor's template arguments in a
>   constructor invocation (because the constructor has no name but is
>   invoked by use of the constructor's class's name)
>
> [...]
>
> It was observed that explicitly specifying the template arguments in a constructor declaration is never actually necessary because the arguments are, by definition, all deducible and can thus be omitted.

Note that normal function templates can have non-deducible template parameters that *must* be supplied explicitly for an instantiation or specialization.

*<sub>Thanks to Davis Herring and M.M for guidance</sub>*

Comment: You should say *why* the explicit argument list is forbidden here (unlike for normal member functions).

Comment: @DavisHerring I've given it a try. If it's totally misleading I won't mind if someone just reverts my edit.

Comment: You linked to cppreference page for class template instantiation, but this is actually a [function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template), the constructor function. Usage (2) in the second numbered list

Comment: @DavisHerring the CWG notes are a reference of sorts... nobody explicitly (hurr) mentioned yet that the problem is that the syntax for member function template explicit instantiation can't be used for constructors (because the constructor "name" isn't actually a function name, syntactically the constructor is like an unnamed function which can be indicated in some contexts by repeating the function name; but overlooked for this context).  The CWG issue is asking whether they should bother amending the standard grammar to fix this but they conclude it's not necessary

Comment: @M.M: Well, that issue is actually the source of the text I cited, and it was discussed again and finally resolved very recently, so yes it’s relevant.  Be warned that the notes don’t capture the fact that the last discussion reached the opposite conclusion—something about ambiguity with the injected-class-name of a class template, I think.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll try to clean it up later Today.

Comment: @DavisHerring and M.M :  Does it look better now? Anything missing or wrong?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Looks good.  I’ll just note that normal function templates can have non-deducible template parameters that *must* be supplied explicitly for an instantiation or specialization.